# Can I optimize this sql Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, optimization

Below is a sample query of what I am trying to do and it gets the job done but I feel like the sub queries are not the best way to go here.  Any pointers?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.UserID,   
    (SELECT COUNT(LoginID) FROM Logins WHERE Success = 1 AND UserID = u.UserID) AS Successful,
    (SELECT COUNT(LoginID) FROM Logins WHERE Success = 0 AND UserID = u.UserID) AS Unsuccessful,        
    (SELECT TOP 1 LoginDate FROM Logins WHERE UserID = u.UserID ORDER BY LoginDate DESC) AS LastLogin
FROM 
    Users u INNER JOIN 
    Logins l ON u.UserID = l.UserID
```

BTW the above example doesn't look like it needs the join but in the real solution I do to get some other columns...

Comment: Can you post the execution plan?

Comment: It seems to me you could do all the querying from logins in one select instead of three by using something like `sum(if success = 0 then 1 else 0 endif)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Am I missing something significant, or could you not do this with a single aggregate query?

```
SELECT u.UserID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Success = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Successful,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Success = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Unsuccessful,
    MAX(LoginDate) AS LastLogin
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Logins l on u.UserID = l.UserID
GROUP BY u.UserID
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by my comment.  I didn't make it an answer because I wasn't sure of the syntax.  Good thing too, because I got it wrong.

Comment: I am curious to see how this performs compared to my pivot example.

Comment: @ChaosPandion I, too, am curious. If anyone has a chance to do the comparison, please share your results with us.

Comment: @OMG Ponies Hey, it's usually the other way around. Cheers. :)

Comment: @djacobson - After taking a look at the execution plan it doesn't look good for me. :)

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Yeah, my first impression was "waay overcomplicated".

Comment: FYI - I just ran this query on a small production server.  I added 50,000 users and about 4M login records.  djacobson's query took about 6 seconds to run; mine (which I have since deleted) took closer to 50 seconds.  ChaosPandions answer also took around 45 seconds.

Comment: I ran both also on my data and djacobson's was consistently the fastest.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Why do you feel my answer was way overcomplicated?

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Subquery primarily.  Last time I compared PIVOT on SS2005 vs MAX(CASE expressions, MAX(CASE was a second faster in that instance.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I have run tests in the past on 2005 and the results showed similar performance. I think the problem in this case is the Over clause. If you compare the two plans my plan has an extra sort which makes up about 24% of the cost. If you remove that the query plan almost the same. *(Two extra compute scalars which come from implicit conversions to int in the Pivot clause)*

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
declare @Users Table (UserID int)
declare @Logins Table (LoginID int, UserID int, LoginDate DateTime, Success Bit)

Insert into @Users
select 1 union select 2

insert into @Logins
select 1, 1, '2010-10-13 6:00:00', 1
union
select 2, 1, '2010-10-13 7:00:00', 0
union
select 3, 1, '2010-10-13 8:00:00', 1
union
select 4, 2, '2010-10-13 6:00:00', 0
union
select 5, 2, '2010-10-13 7:00:00', 1
union
select 6, 2, '2010-10-13 9:00:00', 1
union
select 7, 2, '2010-10-13 10:00:00', 1

Select    UserID,
          [1] As Successful,
          [0] As Unsuccessful,
          LoginDate As LoginDate
From (
    SELECT
        u.UserID, 
        l.LoginID,
        l.Success,
        Max(LoginDate) Over (Partition By u.UserID) As LoginDate
    FROM @Users u 
        INNER JOIN @Logins l ON u.UserID = l.UserID
) Data Pivot (
    Count(LoginID) For Success In (
        [0], [1]
    )
) Result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try if this is more efficient in your situation:

```
select
  u.UserID,   
  sum(case when l.Success = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Successful,
  sum(case when l.Success = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Unsuccessful,
  max(LoginDate) as LastLogin
from 
  Users u
  inner join Logins l on l.UserID = u.UserID
group by
  u.UserId
```